# Accessing play project database with h2-browser

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, h2

I am having some trouble accessing the mem database via the `h2-browser` on a `Play` framework project.

With the configuration below, that I think is the correct one (apparently not!) I am getting a h2-browser, but with no tables (beside schema, that is), even though I have applied some migrations.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

conf/application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
```

[image: conf]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you are using in-mem databases actually you are accessing two different databases (although with the same path). You have two solutions:

1. First from your console start bare 'play' console, run h2-browser and finally run your app (withinh the same `play` console)
2. Run H2 in [server mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server), additional beneffit from this approach is fact that you won't loose your data at every app's restart as DB is stored in the file. Then you can access this database from many points (also from 'standalone' H@ browser or some other GUI) with path similar to:

Unix (`~` means your home directory)

`db.default.url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/some/path/to/MyPlayDB"`

or Windows

`db.default.url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/c:/some/path/to/MyPlayDB"`

Note that for best performance in production mode it's worthy switch back to embedded mode, however for dev stage that solution should be good enough (still faster than for an example MySQL)

Comment: I tried your solution 1, and the tables still do not show up. So the actual answer to the question would be to use solution 2?

Comment: @nemoo - just tested with brand new Play 2.2.0 - first approach works as required _still_

Comment: I also tried solution 1, and have the same problem. I start Play console, run h2-browser, log into the h2-browser web screen. Then using the same console, I run "run". When accessing my website I get "Cannot connect to database [default]". Am I missing something? Connection string is "jdbc:h2:mem:play" and I'm using Play 2.2.1

Comment: @according2me run h2-browser, do NOT log in to the database, "run" your application, access your application on the browser "http://localhost:9000/ ...", you will probably have to upgrade/create your db, then, finally log into the h2-browser web screen.

Comment: Solution 1 is perfect and works with newest Play 2.4, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

To browse the contents of your database via the [H2 Web Console](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#tutorial_starting_h2_console), start both the web console and the Play application via the *same* Play console:

1. At first, enter the Play console by running the Typesafe Activator:
   `~/Projects/play-app $ activator`
2. Start the web console:
   `[play-app] $ h2-browser`

   This should open the H2 console interface in your browser.
3. Run the Play app:
   `[play-app] $ run`
4. Access the Play app in your browser. This will cause the Play application to connect to the in-memory H2 database and to initialize it with some default data, if any.
5. Log in to the H2 web console in your browser to inspect the database content. Use the following settings which you can save (for instance, as `Play-App In-Memory Database`) to easily access them again later:

   - Driver Class: `org.h2.Driver`
   - JDBC URL: `jdbc:h2:mem:play`
   - User Name: `sa`
   - Password: `<blank>`

Note that the above settings have to match your actual configuration (`db.default.url` and so on).