# Can't access H2 in-mem database Play! Framework

Tags: playframework, h2, playframework-2.2

I'm very new to play! framework and I looked through a lot of questions but maybe I'm missing something.
I followed [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaDatabase) official tutorial but when I run `play h2-browser` it sends me to `http://192.168.1.36:8082/` and the link doesn't work. Chrome says `The page is not available` What's the reason? Do I have to actually install H2 database on my computer?

If any specific information needed pls let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989171/accessing-play-project-database-with-h2-browser

Comment: @Mikesname nah  that is a quite different problem. This guy can open h2 GUI, but I can't

Comment: @Mikesname do I have to install H2 separately or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to [download](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) install it on your computer.
After installation go to where you installed it and then go to bin and run H2 Windows Batch file, if you are on Windows.