# Wrong user name when accessing play project database with h2-browser

Tags: h2, playframework-2.3

Unable to access play project embedded H2 database, i followed recommendations, and 
 run h2-browser within the same play console as explained here:

[Accessing play project database with h2-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989171/accessing-play-project-database-with-h2-browser)

My Play framework settings ( 2.3.10)

```
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""
```

But i keep getting this error: **Wrong user name or password [28000-180] 28000/28000 (Help)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Play 2.3.x JDBC datasource is managed by BoneCP

## Correctly define User name

```
 db.default.user=sa
```

So I used settings from more recent version
Play framework 2.5.x is using HikaryCP where this would be correct

```
 db.default.username=sa
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273009/how-do-you-view-contents-of-play-2-7-h2-database-using-h2-browser/61552917#61552917), I tried to describe.

**Reason:**

When connecting to the H2 database for the first time, the H2 database initializes the user name and password, but properties the database user name and password are defined in the configuration file , causing a conflict.

**Solution:**

1. Close the program and close the database connection (if the program is not closed, an error will be reported and cannot be changed)
2. Delete the database and delete the xml file in dataSources under .idea
3. Recreate the database and start the project